# Configuring WCF service for reading messages from windows server service bus

Tags: wcf, wcf-binding, servicebus, azureservicebus, azure-servicebus-queues

I am trying to configure WCF SVC with the following configuration. Its not fetching the messages from the window server service bus topic/subscrition.

when i host and configure the same dynamically through code, it works .

```
<bindings>
      <customBinding>
        <binding name="messagingBinding">
          <textMessageEncoding  messageVersion="None"  writeEncoding="utf-8" />
          <netMessagingTransport/>
        </binding>
      </customBinding>

    </bindings>
    <behaviors>
      <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior name="securityBehavior">
          <transportClientEndpointBehavior>
            <tokenProvider>
              <windowsAuthentication domain="****" password="*****" userName="****">
                <stsUris>
                  <stsUri value="https://{machine/domain}:9355/SampleNamespace" />
                </stsUris>

              </windowsAuthentication>
            </tokenProvider>
          </transportClientEndpointBehavior>


        </behavior>
      </endpointBehaviors>
<services>

      <service name="Myservice.IntegrationService">
        <endpoint name="AccountingEndPoint"
                   listenUri="sb://{machine/domain}:9355/SampleNamespace/accounting/subscriptions/sub"
                   address="sb://{machine/domain}:9355/SampleNamespace/accounting"
                   binding="customBinding"
                   bindingConfiguration="messagingBinding"
                   contract="Myservice.IAccounting"
                   behaviorConfiguration="securityBehavior" />
      </service>
    </services>



[ServiceContract]
    public interface IAccounting
    {
        [OperationContract(IsOneWay = true, Action = "*"), ReceiveContextEnabled(ManualControl = true)]
        void AccountingReader(Message message);
    }
```

Comment: Do you get an error? What does it say? Are you using the same URIs in both cases? The URIs you use in your configuration aren't valid

Comment: I don't get any error, what URIs are not valid can u please elaborate ?

Comment: you are correct Panagiotis Kanavos. It should be sb://{machine/domain}/SampleNamespace/accounting/subscriptions/sub sb://{machine/domain}/SampleNamespace/accounting